# Perl UTF-8 problems with Locale::Maketext

Tags: perl, utf-8

**The short story:**
I've encountered a strange problem with Locale::Maketext. Something turns german umlauts into ISO-8859-1 encoding when using
the "use utf8" pragma in my lexicon.

**The long story:**
In my web application everything is kept in UTF-8:

- the database
- the source code files
- the html doctype
- and everything else as far a I can tell

I use **Locale::Maketext** for L10N and all mit Lexicons are defined in Perl Modules which are kept in UTF-8 and 
"use utf8". All languages tested so far (e.g. pt, pl, fr, en, zh, ko, et. al.) work fine except the locale de.
As long a "**use utf8**" is enabled within this language's Lexicon something turns the german umlauts (probably everything thats
no 7-bit ASCII) into ISO-8859-1. I have the script that verifies that everything in my source tree is encoded in UTF-8 (inclduing 7-bit ASCII of course).

Let me repeat: **If I remove the "use utf8"** pragma for the Module MyApp::L10N::de the resulting encoding after using maketext in **my app is UTF-8** which is fine. As long as the module uses **utf8** the encoding **is turned into ISO-8859-1** while all other languages work. I'm desperate to find out why, since this doesn't quite match what I've read about the utf8 pragma.

**My Question is simple: Why does this happen?** How can I *fix* this behaviour, i.e. how do I make my app work with use utf8 in **all** source files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found myself a solution: Setting all input and output to utf8 did work. Perl did some stupid conversions.

I've just put this at the very beginning of my script:

```
binmode STDIN, ":utf8";
binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";
binmode STDERR, ":utf8";
```

Answer (score 1):

The failure you are experiencing is documented in [Locale::Maketext::Gettext](http://p3rl.org/Locale::Maketext::Gettext#NOTES):

> An essential benefit of this Locale::Maketext::Gettext over the original Locale::Maketext(3) is that: GNU gettext is multibyte safe, but Perl source is not. […] Sorry to say this, but it is weird for a localization framework to be not multibyte-safe.

You are advised to migrate off Maketext to a Gettext-based solution, see [rassie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6460/rassie)'s remarkable rocalisation rant: http://rassie.org/archives/247

Comment: I am not sure if I get this right: You're saying that Maketext is not multibyte (i.e. UTF8) safe? Why are my other Lexcions working (e.g. arabic or chinese) and why does the german lexicons work as soon as I remove the use utf8 pragma? This does not make sens to me, yet.

Comment: Read the linked documentation for the details I omitted in the quoted excerpt. I have nothing to add to this.